# How to execute a string of conditional commands which includes a shell command?

Tags: shell, vim

I currently have the following **auto-command** (in my vimrc) -

```
autocmd BufEnter *.c nmap <F5> :Makexec<CR> 
  \:if findfile( expand("%:p:r").".exe" ,expand("%:p:h") ) != ""<CR>
  \    :!%:p:r.exe<CR>
  \:else<CR>
  \    :vert topleft cwin<CR>
  \    :vert resize 50<CR>
  \:endif<CR>
```

I want to convert this auto-command such that it executes a single string where the string contains the above commands chained together.

- Attempt 1

  ```
  let g:c_exe_str="Makexec | if findfile(expand(\"%:p:r\").\".exe\", expand(\"%:p:h\")) != \"\" | !%:p:r.exe | else | vert topleft cwin | vert resize 50 | endif"

  autocmd BufEnter *.c nmap <F5> :execute g:c_exe_str<CR>
  ```

  This didn't work as I had expected, I get the following error at the shell -

  > C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c D:\NewFolder\c_experiments.exe | else |
  >   vert topleft cwin | vert resize 50 | endif
  >   'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
- Attempt 2

  ```
  let g:c_exe_str="Makexec | if findfile(expand(\"%:p:r\").\".exe\", expand(\"%:p:h\")) != \"\" | echo system(expand(\"%:p:r\").\".exe\") | else | vert topleft cwin | vert resize 50 | endif"

  autocmd BufEnter *.c nmap <F5> :execute g:c_exe_str<CR>
  ```

  This kinda (sic) works but without displaying the executable's output in a shell window; basically it doesn't work the same way as the original auto-command.

How do I go about exactly mimicking the original auto-command's steps using execute()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In attempt 1, try to encapsulate `!%:p:r.exe` in a `exe` command :

```
... | exe "!%:p:r.exe" | else ...
```

Otherwise the bar, and everything following a `:!` command is passed to the shell.